# Fonts embedding in DynamicReports for Chinese characters in pdf

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

How to embedded fonts when using *DynamicReports* to display chinese. I have been trying to embed fonts to display Chinese in my pdf reports since a long time but I am not able to ,,I am using *DynamicReports* by Ricardo Mariaca. Even tried every possible option available on net as well as on [website of Dynamic Reports](http://dynamicreports.org/documentation/fonts)

Tried the above link as well.
I Created Fonts.xml, jasper_extension.properties file  but of no use, infact when I try to copy paste arialuni.ttf file in my eclipse package, then it dosen't get displayed in eclipse but when I check the location of package, the font file is present at that location .

Please help, really important.

'let me know for any clarification